# Why can my build not checkout files but I as a developer can?

Tags: tfs, tf-cli

Our build account does not seem to be able to checkout files if they are already checked out.

```
tf.exe checkout.
```

Heres the error:

> TF10151: Cannot lock item $/Scrum2012/Button.htm for check-out.  This
>   item is checked out by ***** in workspace ****.

However I and other developers can checkout files already checked out. Is this a permissions issue?

Is there any way to get over it from the command line? tf.exe checkout /lock:****?

(I still don't get the checkout /lock documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1yft8zkw.aspx)

Comment: Have you compared your source control permissions to the build account permissions? You can do this via Source Code Explorer or via the command line: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252587(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I'll do a comparison. Is there any way to override the permissions for the purposes of checkout? I'd guess not.

Comment: Is there a TFS command to get permissions for certain users?